# android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android

I am totally new at Android Studio.
I am trying to write simple application with 2 screens and passing info from screen 1 to screen 2.

This is the code of the Second activity.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("com.gmail.zionrevi.SOMETHING")) {

        String text = getIntent().getExtras().get("com.gmail.zionrevi.SOMETHING").toString();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText(text);
   }
}
```

}

when i am running it i am getting the following Run Time exception:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

on the following line

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

What i am doing wrong?
can someone help me please?

Comment: can you post your activity xml file

Comment: post the error logs and xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast `ConstraintLayout` into `TextView` which cannot succeed. They are two completly different view.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:id="@+id/textView"
                                         android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

You need to set `TextView` in you xml layout or change `ConstraintLayout` id to some other id and set `TextView` id to textView

Answer (score 0):

Part of learning Android is understanding the errors. When you're told that `typeX cannot be cast to typeY` it almost always means you're attempting to cast something to the wrong type.

In this case, it appears to be occurring here `TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);`. When you do something such as `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview)`, you're casting whatever is returned by `findViewById(...)` to a `TextView`. If that ID you pass to the function is not a TextView, you will get a `ClassCastException`

In your case, very likely, you have a `ConstrainLayout` in your .xml file for this activity that has an ID of `textview`.

Comment: the id that is passing to TextView is a TextView so actually nothing need to be cast. I am not sure i understand the ContstrainLayout  issue. how i can check my .xml file and how i am fixing the problem and make it work?

Comment: Can you post your XML? The error indicates you have a ConstraintLayout assigned an id of `textview`.

Comment: Post activity_second.xml from your `res/layout` directory. It appears you have a ConstrainLayout there that has an id field set like `android:id="@+id/textview"` which is why you're seeing this problem.

Comment: yes, you are right. what should i do to fix the problem?

Comment: ok guys, thanks for the help i was able to fix the problem and to make it work.

Comment: If you post the XML, I can help you better. But if the ConstrainLayout is what you want as a TextView, you're going to have to change that in the XML. But you should definitely change the ConstraintLayout id to something else. If you want the text to display in a TextView within the ConstraintLayout, make sure your TextView has an appropriate id, and that's what you'd pass into your `findViewById(...)` function. But again, I really can't help without the XML.

Answer (score 0):

welcome at android programming ..
i think that your `R.id.textview` refers to [ConstraintLayout]
you should set your [textview] id to be [@+id/textview] and of course clear it from yourConstraintLayout  .. and it will be 
solved :)
happy programming